# Can the themeing and render api be accessed independently?

Tags: theming

Are there de-coupled versions of the form rendering and theming APIs that can be used outside of the Drupal framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in Drupal 7 or earlier. There might be chances for Drupal 8. But in the currently available major versions of Drupal the mentioned components are still strongly integrated in the core system.